# SMS 2003 to SCCM 2012 R2 migration in different Domain Environment

Tags: sms, sccm-2012-r2

I have existing SMS (Primary) on 2003 R2 Server in Forest HP and on one of it's child Domain DF, now I am setting up a new child Domain SD with SCCM 2012 R2 (Primary) in the same Forest HP.

1. What is the best practice to move all clients from SMS 2003 to new SCCM 2012 R2?
2. Is there any upgrade path without uninstalling agent from SMS 2003 and re-installing from SCCM 2012 R2?

Comment: You HAVE TO use the new SCCM Agent.  I will answer your questions in a bit and explain.

Comment: do you mean after moving/joining the client machines to new domain environment we need to push or install new agent from SCCM 2012 R2?